# Angularjs autocomplete directive in 2 places in same dom

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive

[image]

Hi,

I am building an autocomplete directive and I need it at two places in the same form. The autocomplete feature works fine but it shows the same directive at both the places. I have attached a image with this question, referring the Image even if I type in teh to colum the country autocomplete is also activated, how to I bind it to only the element where user is interacting ?

following is my code for the directive

```
angular.module('xyz').directive('autoComplete',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
return {
    restrict:'AE',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        selectedTags:'=model',
        userdata:'=',
        name:'@'
    },
    templateUrl: function(elem,attr){  return 'views/rad/layout/autocomplete.html' },
    link:function(scope,elem,attrs){

        scope.suggestions=[];
        scope.selectedTags=[];
        scope.selectedIndex=-1; //currently selected suggestion index
        scope.search=function(){

            var newSuggestions = [];
//                if(attrs.userdata.indexOf(scope.searchText)===-1){
//                    //dataUser.unshift(scope.searchText);
//                }
                for(var i=0; i < scope.userdata.length;i++)
                {
                         if(dataUser[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1){

                     newSuggestions.push(dataUser[i]);
                }
            }

            scope.suggestions =  newSuggestions;
            scope.selectedIndex = -1; 
        }


        scope.checkKeyDown=function(event){
            console.log(event.keyCode);
            if(event.keyCode===40){//down key, increment selectedIndex                        
                event.preventDefault();
                if(scope.selectedIndex+1 !== scope.suggestions.length){
                    scope.selectedIndex++;
                }
            }
            else if(event.keyCode===38){ //up key, decrement selectedIndex
                event.preventDefault();
                if(scope.selectedIndex-1 !== -1){
                    scope.selectedIndex--;
                }
            }
            else if(event.keyCode===13){ //enter pressed
                scope.addToSelectedTags(scope.selectedIndex);
            }
        }


        scope.addToSelectedTags=function(index){
             if(scope.selectedTags.indexOf(scope.suggestions[index])===-1){
                 scope.selectedTags.push(scope.suggestions[index]);
                 scope.searchText='';
                 scope.suggestions=[];
             }
        }

        scope.$watch('selectedIndex',function(val){
            if(val!==-1) {
                scope.searchText = scope.suggestions[scope.selectedIndex];
            }
        });

        scope.removeTag=function(index){
           scope.selectedTags.splice(index,1);
           }
        }
    }
}])
```

following is the auto complete template

```
<div class="tags-wrapper">
<div id="tagsList" class="tags-cloud">
    <div class="suggestionListing">
        <div ng-repeat="selectedTag in selectedTags track by $index" class="tag">
            <span class="tagName">{{selectedTag}}</span>
            <span>&nbsp;<b ng-click="removeTag($index)" class="fa fa-times cross"></b></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="{{inputname}}"placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="searchInput" class="form-control no-border" ng-model="searchText" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" class="form-control"  ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()"/>

        <div  class="suggestions-list">
            <div ng-repeat="suggestion in suggestions track by $index" class="blockSpan" ng-click="addToSelectedTags($index)" ng-mouseover="$parent.selectedIndex=$index" ng-class="{active : selectedIndex===$index}">
                <div class="userAvatar">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="userInfo">
                    {{suggestion}}
                </div>
                <br clear="all" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```